# How to add 3 columns 2 rows and flip each card independent in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to display 3 columns and 2 rows with flashcards in HTML and flip each card independently when hover the mouse. So far I have one column and two rows but they are also flipping at the same time they are not independent. How can I achieve that? I want to display six cards on-screen and flip them separately. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <title>CSS Card Flip</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #ffffff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: in-line;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    /* THE MAINCONTAINER HOLDS EVERYTHING */
    
    .maincontainer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 320px;
      background: none;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    /* THE CARD HOLDS THE FRONT AND BACK FACES */
    
    .thecard {
      position: relative;
      top: 5;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /* THE PSUEDO CLASS CONTROLS THE FLIP ON MOUSEOVER AND MOUSEOUT */
    
    .thecard:hover {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    /* THE FRONT FACE OF THE CARD, WHICH SHOWS BY DEFAULT */
    
    .thefront {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #00843d;
      color: #000;
    }
    /* THE BACK FACE OF THE CARD, WHICH SHOWS ON MOUSEOVER */
    
    .theback {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #ffd100;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    /*This block (starts here) is merely styling for the flip card, and is NOT an essential part of the flip code */
    
    .thefront h1,
    .theback h1 {
      font-family: 'zilla slab', sans-serif;
      padding: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .thefront p,
    .theback p {
      font-family: 'zilla slab', sans-serif;
      padding: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /*This block (ends here) is merely styling for the flip card, and is NOT an essential part of the flip code */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="maincontainer">

    <div class="thecard">

      <div class="thefront">
        <h1>Front of Card</h1>
        <p>This is the front of the card. It contains important information. Please see overleaf for more details.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="theback">
        <h1>Back of Card</h1>
        <p>Your use of this site is subject to the terms and conditions governing this and all transactions.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="thecard">

      <div class="thefront">
        <h1>Front of Card</h1>
        <p>This is the front of the card. It contains important information. Please see overleaf for more details.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="theback">
        <h1>Back of Card</h1>
        <p>Your use of this site is subject to the terms and conditions governing this and all transactions.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/xodwegs0/ I put your code into a fiddle and they are not flipping at the same time

Comment: if you move the mouse up and down the flip gets synchronized. How can I have 3 columns and two rows as well?

Comment: Use grid to layout the cards and flex to control the card contents . [Good grid guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)